# Perl REGEX repetive capture groups when post processing output file

Tags: regex, perl, capture-group

I am dealing with a string of numbers in scientific format. for example

```
24  6.924E+06  8.316E-01  1.052E-01  1.622E+01  1.311E+01  0.000E+00  6.059E-06 (snip.. extends for a bit)
```

Now I want to write a regex for perl which allows me to capture the ith value in the list. So my current set up is the folloiwng

```
$_ =~ ^\s+\d+\s+(\d+[.]\d+E[+]\d+);
my $temp = $1;
```

Which will get me the first number. I want to be able to capture the 7th or the 50th if I wanted without having to write a really long regex expression.

is there a concise way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
my @cols = split ' ', $_;

my $seventh = $cols[6];
my $fiftieth = $cols[49];
```

Answer (score 2):

split is the best option for this case.

```
my @val = split ' ', $_;
my $val7 = $val[6];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @web-tiki: this answer is exactly the same as [Miller's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24833984/20938), which has six upvotes as I write this.

Comment: @AlanMoore if you check the edit history of this answer, you will see it was edited after my comment.

Comment: I see!  So it morphed from a non-answer to a duplicate answer.  Objection retracted.

Answer (score 0):

An example for the third number:

```
^\s+\d+(?:\s+(\d+\.\d+E[-+]?\d+)){3}
```

When you repeat a capture group, the content is overwritten with the last match.

NB: in this case, it is more clean to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` since you only need arabic digits.

Comment: I found this answer to be the cleanest for my usage.