# Preserve float value from PERL REGEX for computation

Tags: regex, perl, floating-point

Having an issue with a portion of my perl script. I am pulling floating point values and i am trying to take the average but it seems to be converting my numbers to integers.

input looks like the following

```
L=  78   0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.110E-07  0.258E-03  
L=  79   0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.181E-07  0.258E-03  
L=  80   0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.494E-05  0.290E-03  
L=  81   0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.112E-04  0.499E-03  
L=  82   0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.000E+00  0.223E-04  0.500E-03
```

my code snip is the following

```
if ($B eq 'test')
                {
                    ($A) += ($_ =~ m/^\s+L=\s+\d+(?:\s+(\d+\.\d+E[-+]?\d+)){7}/);
                }
```

now this is in the context of a loop and the value i am getting is the following as i read in the 7th value from the listing above for example. ( using lines 79-82

```
     value 1
     value 2
     value 3
     value 4
```

if i change the += to just a = i get the correct values but i cannot manipulate them at all without destroying the contents. How do i preserve the float value when doing operations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm...that regex isn't matching the file input at all for me.  Is `$temp` set to something prior to call the regex?

Comment: @Vinbot hi sorry yeah temp resolves to a int value. The full script takes different numbers. I updated replacing with a fixed value to focus on the issue at hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into some weird Perl quirks.

In the expression `($A) = ($_ =~ /regexp/);` the regex is used in a list context because the left-hand side of the assignment is a list (a one element list, but still a list). In list context a successful regex match returns the list of captured groups (or, if the regex doesn't capture any groups, the list `(1)`).

In your case, because you have a subgroup matching a float, `$A` gets assigned that number.

The expression `($A) += ($_ =~ /regexp/);` looks almost the same but here the addition forces scalar context. This means the result of the regex will be 1 (true) if there is a match or the empty string (false) if there is none.

Again, in your case, you count the successful matches.

Now for your problem, you don't need any complicated regular expressions. You can simply split on whitespace and get the numbers in an array:

```
$_ =~ s/^\s+//;  # delete any leading spaces
my @data = split(/\s+/, $_);
```

Comment: @TheCodeNovice This answers your current question, but I want to point out that I also advised you to use split 2 days ago in your earlier problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24833934/1733163  Don't use regular expressions if there are simpler tools to accomplish the job.  Namely, if one has columned data, split is likely the best tool for the job.

Comment: @Miller Now I can see why you suggested that route, I was trying to make my code compact but I can see now that some steps cannot be avoided.

Comment: Instead of going for compactness, go for readability.  By using the precise tool for the job, it makes your code more self documented.  For example, when someone sees the use of split, it's obvious that you're working with columned data.  However, using a regex for everything obscures what is happening in the code, which both makes code more fragile and also harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're adding to `$A` an array, not a single element of the array.  Add `[0]` to the match like this:

`$A += ($text =~ m/^\s+L=\s+\d+(?:\s+(\d+\.\d+E[-+]?\d+)){7}/)[0];`